# Google Backend Tutorial Web App doesn't work

Tags: android, backend

I am trying to make this tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

But the checkin entity won't show on the web app as shown on the photo of the tutorial. Instead of it there is a blank dropdown box. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are stuck?

Maybe this Codelab can help you. http://j.mp/1rm88Fe